# How to store global temp info in Angular without using LocalStorage

Tags: node.js, angular, global-variables

In an angular 10 App, after user authentication, some sensitive information was fetched from server side(like tokens used in another Api). And i don't want to store them in LocalStorage because it is too easy to find.

But i need to access to these informations from one angular service(let's call it `ApiService`), what is the best way to store these sensitive informations?

I think the essential question is, could Angular provide a way to store global variables in memory? (Like a static class in Java)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by LocalStorage is easy to find? No other websites have access to LocalStorage items created by your site and anybody that has physical access to the machine can find anything that you store client side.

Use an Angular service that is provided in root and any component or service can request that service to access data stored in it. Provided in root means it will be a singleton and all requests for that service will get the same instance.

If you don't want a rouge library you have used or a XSS attack to have access to some information you need to store client side then a http only cookie is your only option. When a cookie is set as http then it will be sent back to node with each request but is not accessible via JavaScript on the client.

Comment: It is the `anybody that has physical access to the machine` situation i am considering, for example a user used the app in a public computer but left without logging off, then another guy could get his token from browser LocalStorage. If this another guy is technical enough he can script to get previous user's data from app database.

I will try the `Angular service that is provided in root` way you mentioned about, sounds like a great idea to avoid expose plaintext token. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, any sensitive information shouldn't be stored at the client-side, knowing that, jwt tokens cannot be hidden because eventually they will be sent at the headers of your secured API calls. and they are not considered as sensitive that in that matter. For that to be valid, **you shouldn't encode sensitive data** within your jwt token.
That being said, jwt security relies on the fact that although the tokens can be known/decoded, a third party cannot temper the token because they are signed using a private key/certificate that only the server knows about.

For the storage, you can use Angular singleton services to achieve in-memory sharing of global state between components, or use more sophisticated  libraries to manage your application state ([ngrx](https://ngrx.io/), [akita](https://datorama.github.io/akita/)...etc.)